# how i can create my command line app like this :$ myApp>

Tags: python, cmd, command

```
$ python myApp>
```

After the app runs I want it to be like the command below:

```
$ myApp> {write options}
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're asking - but I think you might be looking for a shell module - in which case I'd recommend [shellac](https://github.com/mrichar1/shellac) or [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/cmd.html) modules.

Answer (score 0):

Run `python`, then type `execfile('myApp.py')` for python2, or `exec(open("./myApp.py").read())` for python3.